# How does the ticket system in Operations work?

Tags: battlefield-1

I have been watching my brother play Battlefield 1 lately, and I understand most of the mechanics. Apparently Conquest mode now gives tickets for holding a flag for a certain period of time, making for a more balanced game than previous battefield games.

But what we (I tried asking him) don't understand is how tickets work in Operations.

The attacking team starts with 150 tickets. They spend these ... by respawning? ... and when they get below 0 (I saw a game stuck at 0 tickets for about 20 seconds so I think it needs to go in the minus), the attacking team loses a try.

But the tickets also go up! During regular play, the ticket counter bounces up and down. 32, 31, 30, 31, 30... So apparently there is some way to get tickets back?

Additionally, when the sector is captured, there's a large and rapid gain of tickets... But this is not a linear growth, so I get the feeling these are awarded for certain things as well.

---

My questions:

- How are tickets spent in Operations?
- How are tickets gained during regular play in Operations?
- How are tickets gained during the clear the sector/retreat section in Operations?

Depending on the answers, I'm also interested in knowing whether you should spawn as an attacker if there are 0 tickets left, and whether you should kill yourself as a defender during retreat.

Comment: I've been assuming that every "retreating" defender that is killed grants the attackers 1 ticket.  I'm pretty sure if a retreating defender suicides, that would be the same as if they were killed by the attackers.  The best thing for a defending player to try to do is to make it back to the next sector alive.  I'm basing most of this off of the score bonuses that pop up on screen in certain conditions, but I haven't seen any kind of authoritative source confirming any of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lot of similarities with Rush. Like in rush, the attackers are given a limited number of reinforcement tickets. In Operations by default it's 250 for 64 players, 200 for 40 players *(150 for both prior to the fall update)*. When an attacker dies, a ticket is lost. When Medics revive a teammate, a ticket is refunded.

When tickets are at zero, game continues as long as there isn't a flag fully in defenders possession (so for example either both are disputed or one is taken by attackers, other is disputed).

Unlike Rush however, in Operations advancing to next set of objectives does not fully reset the ticket count, instead you get additional 50 tickets (30 prior to patch). There is however an opportunity to gain some additional tickets. Retreating defenders are marked and killing each of them grants attackers **3** tickets *(2 prior to the fall update)*

Comment: source for that quoted text?

Comment: Its strange that when you take a sector in an operation, its almost always 30 ish tickets the attackers get back (in 64 player games at least), but I highly doubt we get about 30 kills every single time we take a sector, since there are at most 32 players on the defending team, and at least several will likely not die retreating.

Comment: @Ryan, you're right. I dug into it deeper and updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

**How are tickets spent in Operations?**

If you are the defending team, you have a unlimited amount of tickets. The ticket loss is only for the attacking team. It's the same as the gamemode Rush.

**How are tickets gained during regular play in Operations?**
I'm not sure how to explain this, but I think if a player of the attacking team dies. They will lose a ticket, but if he is revived by a teammate the team gets the ticket back. But when you respawn as the attacking team, you will lose a ticket. The ticket count is the same as how much you can respawn.

**How are tickets gained during the clear the sector/retreat section in Operations?**
I don't know it yet, because i have only played a few operation matches

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer with a bit more detail than this. Do you lose a ticket upon spawning or upon dying? If there are 0 tickets left, should I spawn or do we instantly lose because I spawn and take a ticket?